# String string = text.getText().toString(). giving NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, string, nullpointerexception

I have a Database that uses a string to get information from the data base. when I use something like:

```
public String getString(String string){
        string = "information";
        return string;
}
```

This gets `infromation` But as soon as I change it to pull from a text view:

```
  public String getString(String string){
        string = textview.getText().toString();
        return string;
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException` error. 
also I have tried to make an intent and pull from the intent:

```
public String getString(String string){
        string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
        return string;
}
```

and

```
 public String getString(String string){
        string = getIntent().getStringExtras("key");
        return string;
}
```

And both ways give me `NullPointerExceptions` on `getExtras()` and  `getStringExtra()` What am I doing wrong

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. Is that method supposed to return text from a TextView? Or an Intent? And what do you mean by "I have tried to make an intent and pull from the intent"? You seem to be using the Activity's Intent there.

Comment: @VikramBodicherla, Yes it is supposed to return text from a TextView. and by "I have tried to make an intent and pull from the intent" I mean I used `Intent intent = new intent(); intent.putExtra("key",text.getText().toString());`

Comment: In that case, you don't need to create an Intent. Did you check if textview.getText() is returning null?

Comment: @VikramBodicherla, textview.getText() does return null

Comment: @VikramBodicherla, Nope, I still get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you might want to retrieve the textview's content first before passing in the value "string" into this method. Eventually the method would look like this.

```
public String getString(String string){    
return string;
}
```

And this, you missed out a closing bracket.

```
public String getString(String string){
string = getIntent().getStringExtras("key";
return string;
}
```